# I want to make mesh network with nodemcu (esp8266)

Tags: esp8266

in this all the nodemcu are in both mode receiving and transmitting, if i made 6 nodemcu connected with each other as mesh network to control home appliances, using mac address.  suggest how i will start to reach the destination.

Comment: How will your nodes find / connect to each other? Basically, keep a table of which nodes connect directly to which other nodes, distribute updates to this table among all devices (for example when devices join, leave or links break) and use this table to find the shortest path to the destination node.

Comment: Can you provide some details (i.e. code) as to what you have done so far and what the problem is that you have encountered?

Comment: till now i only tested nodemcu range and communication from master to slave. but i wanted to extend more to communicate all the node mcu's with each other.

Comment: i got some ways to broadcast the data using MAC address of receivers. but the problem is how i connect all the nodemcu as STATION and AP mode at the same time. in mesh network in which all the nodemcu are communicating each other.

Answer (score 1):

there are libraries for this already, i have used [this one,](https://github.com/martin-ger/esp_wifi_repeater) but i have not tested the mesh function yet

Comment: im using painless mesh